Active Directory user not visible in ADUC but synced to Office 365
We currently have a user being synced from our AD to our 365, but we cannot locate the user's object inside ADUC.
I can confirm that the user's not been deleted since its not on the recycle bin and is not showing when we try to query any recently deleted objects via powershell.
Get-ADObject -ldapFilter:"(msDS-LastKNownRDN=") -IncludeDeletedObjects
Also tried to query the user via its SID and objectID but still seeing nothing.
Odd thing is the user in question is still being synced without any errors.

If the user is not deleted from AD and is still not visible, you can restore it using LDP. Follow the link for more details

Thank you @VenkatV! Will try and keep you posted

Hi @Ryan, Are you able to resolve the issue by following the link?
